# Adding WindowsPhone8.1 project to Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, xamarin.forms

As per [Xamarin's Document](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/getting-started/phone/) I added the windows phone application to Xamarin.Forms project.

But, Step 5 is giving me error saying "Cannot create an instance of WindowsPhonePage".

```
<forms:WindowsPhonePage

xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT"
x:Class="XamarinTest.WinPhone81.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:XamarinTest.WinPhone81"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">  

</forms:WindowsPhonePage>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a LOT of trial and error, I solved it. **Guide didnt mention it**, but I added `Xamarin.Forms.Windows` from NuGet and it solved the problem.